# Android RecyclerView item width doesn't match parent and preview doesn't match emulator

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-emulator

This is my recycler view items xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerItem"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerItemImageView"
           android:padding="8dp"
           android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       </ImageView>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerItemTextView"
           android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:text="item"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       </TextView>

   </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And preview show me like this:

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRSyk.png)

But emulator result this:

[Emulator result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7nR5.png)

So items in recycler view does not match parent width on emulator. Other xml's there are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:name="com.example.databinding_practice.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/activityTextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityTextView"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter class and ListFragment like this:

RecyclerAdapter.kt:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(var recyclerItems: ArrayList<RecyclerItemModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>() {

    class RecyclerViewHolder(val binding: RecyclerItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        val binding = RecyclerItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        return RecyclerViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.recyclerItemTextView.text = recyclerItems[position].text
        recyclerItems[position].imageMipmapSource?.let { holder.binding.recyclerItemImageView.setImageResource(it) }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return recyclerItems.size
    }
}
```

ListFragment.kt:

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {
    private var itemList : ArrayList<RecyclerItemModel> = arrayListOf()
    private var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(arrayListOf())
    private lateinit var fragmentListBinding: FragmentListBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        fragmentListBinding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return fragmentListBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        for (i in 0..3){
            itemList.add(RecyclerItemModel(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Item $i"))
        }



        fragmentListBinding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        fragmentListBinding.recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
        recyclerAdapter.recyclerItems = itemList
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Where am I doing wrong? If I replace match parent to fixed size like 200 dp - 300dp , thats working correctly but match parent does not. And why preview and emulator does not match ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you debug with layout inspector ? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector Also you need to check your `inflate` call (replace with this `inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)`)

Comment: When I replaced `RecyclerItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)` this works for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment you should change **layout_width** and **layout_height** to **"0dp"** in your RecyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It has no effect :( , problem was layout inflating. This should be `RecyclerItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)`. Thank you.

Comment: is there a version of this for Java? I'm unable to find `RecyclerItemBinding`

Comment: @reactor No , RecyclerItemBinding is a binding class generated by viewbinding if you are using viewbinding features in project. Here [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)